# Rails index method display parent with child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

know this is a bone-headed question, but I cant find what im looking for.

I have two models: parent and child

```
class child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end

class parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs
end
```

in the child controller index action I would like to display a field from the parent model with each of the queried records.

```
def index
  @childs = Childs.all
end
```

How do I display the parent_name in the view with the child records?

for example:

```
<%= @childs.each do |c| %>
  <%= child.name %>
  <%= child.parent.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For those reading this in the future, it might be an idea to use `children` - the plural form of child, rather than `childs`. my two cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of issues that I found with your code.

- Your model names should be capitalized.
- When setting the association, your `childs` should be `children`.
- When setting `@childs`, your should reference the model as `Child`, not `Childs`
- You're looping through each record of the children with `c` but you reference them as `child`
- There is no need for `<%=` in the first line.

Correcting these should look like this and it should work. If you are having other issues, post the error message and relevant code.

**Models**

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end
```

**Controller**

```
def index
  @childs = Child.all
end
```

**View**

```
<% @childs.each do |child| %>
  <%= child.name %>
  <%= child.parent.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ive marked your answer as correct because you have pointed out the correct way.  After alot of trial and error, it has become clear that my problem, is that Im using Devise(parent model) with rails 4. and without the attr-accesable(or rails 4 equiv.) im getting a nil class error.  If you have any ideas for fixing this please let me know.

Comment: @kobaltz thank you for your answer. I won't `child.parent.name` hit the database everytime? If so, is there a way to minimise this impact?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a nil class, maybe it's because your :parent_id doesn't carry your parent's id when creating the record.

You may go to rails console and enter 'Child.all' to see if all your :parent_ids are nil or not.

I myself have a user model that has_many :tweets，and each tweet model belongs_to :user. In my tweet.controller.rb, I set up the def create as follows to enter user's id into :user_id column:

```
def create
    @tweet = current_user.tweets.new(tweet_params)
    if @tweet.save
      flash[:notice] = "You've updated with a tweet."
      redirect_to admin_tweets_path
    else
      @tweets = Tweet.all
      render :index
    end
  end
```